# Is context value shared between Provider instances derived from the same context in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am having a Provider component whose values I export by means of a hook.

The simple implementation of what I am describing is this:

```
// SomeProvider.jsx
const SomeContext = React.createContext(null);

function SomeProvider(props) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    //some logic
    setState(newValue)
  }, [props.someValue])

  return <SomeContext.Provider value={state} {...props} />;
}

const useSome = () => React.useContext(SomeContext);

export { SomeProvider, useSome };
```

Now, what if i want to use this context provider in more than one place? for example

```
// App.jsx
<SomeProvider someValue={valueOne}>
  <SomeComponent />
</SomeProvider>
<SomeProvider someValue={valueTwo}>
  <SomeOtherComponent />
</SomeProvider>
```

where `valueOne` and `valueTwo` are subject to change

```
// SomeComponent.jsx
import { useSome } from 'SomeProvider';

function SomeComponent() {
  const someValue = useSome();

  return ....
}
```

```
// SomeOtherComponent.jsx
import { useSome } from 'SomeProvider';

function SomeOtherComponent () {
  const someValue = useSome();

  return ....
}
```

Will this approach lead to the two `SomeProvider` instances sharing a common value, thus messing up things?

If that's the case what would be the correct approach to end up with each `SomeProvider` having its own "private" value?

If that's not the case, how does this work, since all Providers are derived from the same `React.useContext()` invocation?

Comment: Did you try it? I'm 99% sure they will not share values since they are providing two different contexts

Comment: I think they will share the same value, since they are derived from the same `React.createContext()` (it's only executed once in the module). I'll make a short demo and come back with answers

Comment: I'm right. just tested it https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-mountain-khig9

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even though `createContext` is only called once, React creates instances of those contexts per rendering of a context Provider. When something calls `useContext`, React will go up the render tree to find the nearest Provider of the given **type** and get that values from the **instance** of that context.

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-mountain-khig9)

Comment: So, if I got this right, in layman terms,  the `createContext(value)` is just passing its `value` to each new `Provider` instance, as an initial value, but after that each instance is completely isolated from each other

Comment: That's right. To be extra clear, the `value` prop on the `Context.Provider` component is optional. You have used it to implement a way to modify the default value passed to `createContext` -- but what you just said is completely correct.